# Error getting JMX attribute value for Hazelcast

Tags: wildfly, jmx, hazelcast

Trying to get values of attributes for ManagedExecutorService of Hazelcast, I get error ReflectionException. With JConsole I can see values normally.

```
String connectionUrl = "service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9990";
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(connectionUrl);

Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<>();
String[]  credentials = new String[] {"developer", "developer"};
auth.put (JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);

JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, auth);
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
try {
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("com.hazelcast:instance=_hzInstance_1_dev,name=\"hz:async\","
            + "type=HazelcastInstance.ManagedExecutorService");
    MBeanInfo info = mbsc.getMBeanInfo(objectName);
    mbsc.getAttribute(objectName, "eventQueueSize"); //exception here
    //AttributeList lst =
    //    mbsc.getAttributes(objectName, new String[]{"eventQueueSize", "completedTaskCount"}); // and here
    //System.out.println(lst);
} finally {
    jmxc.close();
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.management.ReflectionException
    at com.hazelcast.jmx.HazelcastMBean.getAttribute(HazelcastMBean.java:115)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.getAttribute(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:1390)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.getAttribute(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:393)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.BlockingNotificationMBeanServer.getAttribute(BlockingNotificationMBeanServer.java:148)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerProxy$GetAttributeHandler.handle(ServerProxy.java:691)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerCommon$MessageReciever$1$1.run(ServerCommon.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor$1.run(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor$1.run(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor.handleEvent(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:70)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerCommon$MessageReciever$1.run(ServerCommon.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You sure the attribute name is eventQueueSize and not EventQueueSize ?

Comment: @Nicholas oops, my fault. Write your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try `queueSize` as it's defined in the `ManagedExecutorServiceMBean` class:

```
@ManagedAnnotation("queueSize")
@ManagedDescription("The work queue size")
public int queueSize() {
    return managedObject.getQueueSize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You sure the attribute name is eventQueueSize and not EventQueueSize ?